# Detect user interactions on device when the application is in the background

Tags: android

When Android device boot up, my application will start working in the foreground. User can put my application to background and he\she can use other applications for a desired long time.

When user stop interaction with phone for 30 seconds or lock the phone, my application will (if required)unlock the phone and continue to become active in the foreground.

How can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

> User can put my application to background and he\she can use other
>   applications for a desired long time.

Starting from Android O you won't be able to reliably make your app work in background. System applies several restrictions on background processing especially running background services. Only alternative would be to create Foreground Service. But if OS detects that you are performing CPU intensive work this won't work either.

> When user stop interaction with phone for 30 seconds or lock the
>   phone, m**y application will (if required)unlock the phone and continue
>   to become active in the foreground**.

Unfortunately its not possible. Even if manage to get Administrator rights there is no API which allows developers to unlock the phone without user's action. This would be a privacy breach.

Comment: even I can not unlock the phone my app still starts working when phone is locked. In this step I don't need to unlock phone. I just need to know is phone at idle mode or user has gestures.

Comment: @MuratVAROL You can Register for `ACTION_SCREEN_ON` & `ACTION_SCREEN_OFF` in your foreground service. Follow this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32891835/android-how-to-detect-when-phone-is-active-and-idle) for implementation details

Comment: How will it help me to catch user interactions such as gestures.

Comment: @MuratVAROL this will help you to detect phone idle state. I am not sure whether its possible to detect the gestures when your app is in background. Since the Gestures are directly delivered to the View on which they occurred and your app doesn't have any visible Views which would receive the Gestures.