# How to call Abstract Class in Another Class when Screen is IDLE in Android Studio

Tags: android

Sorry for the duplicate of question title, but others ask is actually different from mine.

**What i want to Achieve**

i want my app to show User the MainActivity when the Screen is idle.

[Original code gotten from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32891835/android-how-to-detect-when-phone-is-active-and-idle)

**What have Done so Far**

ScreenReceiver.class

```
public class ScreenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        private boolean screenOff;

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF))    {
                screenOff = true;
            } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
                screenOff = false;
            }
            Intent i = new Intent(context, UpdateService.class);
            i.putExtra("screen_state", screenOff);
            context.startService(i);
        }

    }
```

ScreenService.class

```
public static class ScreenService extends Service {

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();
            IntentFilter filter = new     IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
            filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
            BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new ScreenReceiver();
            registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
            boolean screenOn = intent.getBooleanExtra("screen_state", false);
            if (!screenOn) {
                //Implement here your code
            } else {
                //Implement here your code
            }
        }
    }
```

Now My MainActivity.class

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ScreenService screenService = new ScreenService() {
            @Nullable
            @Override
            public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
                return null;
            }
        };

        screenService.onCreate();
    }

}
```

**Now this is the error my getting**

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'android.content.Intent
>   android.content.Context.registerReceiver(android.content.BroadcastReceiver,
>   android.content.IntentFilter)' on a null object reference

**how do i solve this??**

Comment: Please don't write edit summaries like that...

Comment: Ok...Thanks Zoe, but honestly, i think u did not read the question detail enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not call `onCreate()` method itself! You did:

```
screenService.onCreate();
```

To run service you should call `startService` method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Intent i = new Intent(this, ScreenService.class);
    // This line starts a service
    startService(i);  
}
```

Comment: I just tried it, yes, no error was found but i tried to Fire a Toast  msg inside the `Screenservic.class` `onStart()` but i go nothing when the screen gone idel

Comment: @user3728868 This link can be helpful: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services#Declaring

Comment: haaaa, no i did not register it at manifest, pls how do i do that?

Comment: oooh thanks the link was helpful, applying the changes now

Comment: app is still running with out error,  the Toast msg was sent but the issue now is, the Toast msg fire only ones, when the app just newly launch

Comment: @user3728868 I think your `ScreenReceiver` doesn't work. It should be registered like `Activity` and `Service`. https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts#receiving-broadcasts

Comment: The `ScreenReciever` is registered, i just put `Log.e()`  inside the `onReceive()` and it was fired every time the app is idle but the issue still remains the Toast inside the `Screenservice` fired ones

Comment: Where you show Toast? inside `onCreate()` or inside `onStart()`? `onCreate()` is called only once, onStart is called every time your call `startService()`.

Comment: inside `onStart()`

Comment: @user3728868 Try to use `onStartCommand` instead `onStart()`. `onStart()` method was deprecated in API level 15.

Comment: @user3728868 I think I know what is wrong. You start `UpdateService` from `ScreenReceiver` but should `ScreenService`.

Comment: i have long chaged that to `ScreenService` since `UPdateService` is no where found inside my project

Comment: pls, i still need help in solving this issue....
Though last night i added a Thread to the `onstartComand()` yes, the Toast started firing but the issue now is even when am in another app, the Toast Keep Firing??
what must i do now??

Comment: @user3728868 I think you must to create a separate question for a new problem.

Comment: Thanks for your help all the way, i will sure create a new thread of question